# Exercise 2.5.6 in Kempf's Algebraic Varieties: Dimension of a variety

Tags: algebraic-geometry, affine-varieties

A variety $X$ by definition has an open cover with finitely many affine varieties $X_1, \dots, X_n$.  The claim is that dimension of $X$ is max of dim $X_i$.

I am not getting anywhere with this problem. So I start with a chain of irreducible closed subsets $\{F_k\}_k$ in $X$. Their intersections $\{F_k \cap X_i\}_k$ will also be closed in the subspace topology of $X_i$, and they would also be irreducible since any open set $F_k \cap X_i$ of an irreducible set $F_k$is (is it true?). But there is no guarantee on strictness of the chain.
Conversely, if i start with a chain of irreducible closed sets in one of the $X_i$, I can't guarantee that I can get a chain of irreducibles in $X$. Any hint would be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

What is your definition for the dimension of a variety? what about the dimension of an affine variety? An approach is the following

$dim X=max_x dim_xX$ (where $dim_xX$ is the dimension of $X$ at $x$)

Moreover for affine varieties, $dimX_i=dim_xX_i$ for all $x\in X_i$ and therefore the result follows.

Comment: The definition is as usual the length of maximal chain of irreducible closed sets in X. The variety X already comes equipped with a topology (such that there exists a finite open cover by affines).  I don't understand your proof of how you go from X to $X_i$

Comment: Do you agree that $dimX=max_xdim_xX$? But since $X_i$ cover X, for all $x\in X$, $x\in X_i$ for some i. But since $X_i$ is affine, $dim_xX=dim_xX_i=dimX_i$